# How to get another page on ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've a problem with my page, first code (let said is hompe.php)

```
<html>
<div id="trackingkp"></div>
</html>
```

then on my ajax I've code like these

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var dataString = '';
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: host+"ajax/tracking/kp",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html)
        {
            $('#trackingkp').html($(html).find('#trackingkp').html());
            //$("#trackingkp").html($(data).find('#trackingkp').html());
        } 
    });     
});
```

and on my ajax controller, I do like these (I'm using framework laravel)

```
public function tracking($url)
{
    //var_dump("AAA");

    $this->view('ajax/tracking/'.$url,[]);
}
```

on my ajax/tracking view like this

```
<?php
    //$json = array();
    $json = "<input type='text'></input>";
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

When I try that is showing

```
 Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "<input type='text'>
```

I have solved the problem, I'm using another option without using jQuery, so on same time, on controller when load view home.php, I try put load view too like these

```
public function index(){

    is_header(); 
    $this->view('home',[]);
    $this->view('ajax/tracking/kp',[]); ---> I add these
    is_footer(); 
}
```

and on ajax/tracking/kp (view)  I put these code

```
<input type='text'></input>
```

and is working.

Comment: What happens when you've tried replaced `<input type='text'></input>` to `'<input type='text' />'` instead on your `$json` variable?

Comment: @eeya :  Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "<input type='text' \/>".

Comment: Hmm double check this: `echo json_encode("<input type='text' />")`. Is it still returns a [syntax] error?

Comment: @eeya : nope result still same  Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "<input type='text' \/>"
I wanna try to get content like requice_once but using jquery & ajax. Cause i need get paramater table & field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be in this one:

```
success: function(html) {
    // Problem : $(html).find('#trackingkp').html(); 
    $('#trackingkp').html($(html).find('#trackingkp').html());
}
```

From which this `html` response is expected to return a `json` value
in your given [controller]

```
<?php
    //$json = array();
    $json = "<input type='text'></input>";
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Thus this is equivalent to:

```
$("<input type='text'></input>").find('#trackingkp').html();
```

In this case, I don't think you might need to call another *.html(). You can simplify / solve this by calling it once:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host+"ajax/tracking/kp",
    dataType: 'json', // Kindly replace [html] to [json] since you are returning a [json] value
    success: function(html) {
        $('#trackingkp').html(html);        
    }
});
```

Hope this helps for your case

Comment: well is kinda working but still showing syntact error unrecognized expression: "<input type='text' \/>" or  Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "<input type='text'><\/input>"

Comment: What response did you got when you've console [html]? `console.log(html)`

Comment: syntact error unrecognized expression: "<input type='text' \/>" or Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "<input type='text'><\/input>" is still same, but nvr mind, i figure out with naother option, u can see my update question, tq for your answer :)

Comment: Noted. Good job